# How to evaluate $\int_C y^2 \,dx + 2xy\,dy$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am asked to evaluate the integral $\int_C y^2 ~dx + 2 x y~ dy$ where $c$ is the curve $(t^8,\sin^7(\frac{\pi t}{2}))$, where $0\leq t\leq 1$.

My attempt so far is:

$dx = 8t^7 dt$ and $dy = \frac{7\pi}{2}\cos(\frac{\pi t}{2})\, dt$

So $\int_C y^2 \,dx + 2xy\,dy = \int_0^1 (8t^7\sin^{14}(\frac{\pi t}{2}) + 2t^8\sin^7(\frac{\pi t}{2}) ) \,dt$

But this seems to be a very difficult integral to solve, so I'm pretty sure my working is incorrect.

Comment: You are trying to calculate the line integrals by definition (parametrization), which is almost always the most difficult way. You have to consider alternative methods: Green's theorem and the potentials (when applied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y^2dx+2xydy=d (xy^2).$  Then the integral does not depend on the path. The initial point is $x_0=0^8=0, y_0=\sin^7 0=0$ and the end point is $x_1=1^8=1,y_1=\sin^7\frac{\pi}{2}=1$. The integral is equal to $1 \times 1^2 - 0 \times 0^2=1$

Comment: Could you please explain how you got $y^2dx+2xydy = d(xy^2)$?

Comment: For a function of 2 variables $U(x,y)$ the differential is $d U(x,y)=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(x,y)dx + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}(x,y)dy.$

Comment: I still don't understand... wouldn't $\frac{du}{dx}(y^2) = 0$ and $\frac{du}{dy}(2xy) = 2x$?

Comment: $U(x,y)=xy^2$. Then  $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=y^2$ and $\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}=2xy$